# Is there an Extension In Magento to automaticaly take a colour from a product image to produce a colour swatch for that product image

Tags: php

My client wants a way for a color swatch that takes the color automatically from the product image. For example I have an image of a a woman in a green dress, is there a way to get the color from say the dead center of that image and create a swatch from it automatically? There doesn't look like there is a way but my client is really insistant as she wants the color swatches from all the products to be an exact match to the product without having to upload different color/images for each one or pick a color from a swatch.

Any help on this would be amazing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well actually there are ways to do this!
Check out this website for example: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/. Here's the project with the javascript file on github: https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief

First, add the file color-thief.js that you get from the github linked and put that into `/skin/frontend/THEME_NAME/default/js`

Then you would include this file into your theme's layout.xml file in `/app/design/frontend/THEME_NAME/default/layout/layout.xml` by finding or adding this xml block:

```
<referece name="root">
    <referance name="head">
```

Then add this line inside of the block above to include the js file on everypage:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js></type><script>js/color-thief.js</script></action>
```

Then go to `/app/design/frontend/THEME_NAME/default/template/catalog/product/view.ptml` and add a `<script>` including:

```
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
colorThief.getColor(sourceImage);
```

You should be able to get `sourceImage` using `$_product->getImageUrl();`

To display the colors themselves you may have to write a bit of javascipt to change the backgrounds of `<div>`s that you would create to make a swatch.